# Deploying OpenCV applications

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, visual-c++

I have made an OpenCV application in VC++, whose executable is in the form of a dll. I am using this dll in a .NET application.

After building the VC++ based OpenCV application, I get the dll. I simply move this dll into the bin folder of the .NET application and I can properly use it in the code.

However, I was wondering how would I build a setup for deployment on a target machines which won't even have any C++ runtime or OpenCV runtime libraries. Can anyone please help me figure out how can I make a setup file for the application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I know you'll need to deploy OpenCV `dll`'s you use in your code (i.e. cxcore, cvcam etc.) and [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647&displaylang=en).

EDIT: You will need MVSC redistributable package only if you use older version of OpenCV which in order to work with OpenMP requires this package. If you use newer version (i.e. `2.0`) this isn't necessary.